# How to keep local file date and time when pushing to GitHub

Tags: git, github

I would like to push one of my old archived projects up to GitHub and I'd like to keep the original file date (27/08/2011). Is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Each commit stores the date the commit has been authored and the date the commit has been committed into the repository.

Performing a `git log --format=fuller` operation of a repository will print those dates.

When you push to GitHub, those commits are being pushed unmodified, with all their meta-data information. Thus the dates those commits have been performed on will be preserved.

Comment: Thanks! In the meantime I found that I have to specify or amend the commit date. Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: Something like `git commit --amend --date="Wed Feb 16 14:00 2037 +0100"` should do the trick. See the [documentation](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-commit.html) for a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: The following almost did the trick:

``SET GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="2011-08-27T21:48:00"``
``SET GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="2011-08-27T21:48:00"``
``git commit -m "archive"``

GitHub says last commit was 7 months ago, but the repository is updated "just now". Hmm, anyway doesn't worth to spend more time on this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: "just now" refers to the lastest push date. It only relates to the repository activity from the GitHub standpoint.